# Error passing array into extension HTML Helper

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, extension-methods, html-helper

So I had plenty of help on here creating this method and getting it working...but since this is someone different I thought I would make another question out of it.

First I had an HTML Helper extension method working by passing in an extra string to determine a permission which I checked for in the extension. I now want to pass in an array of strings (permissions), and loop through them in the method, but I am getting this error:

CS1501: No overload for method 'CheckBoxForWithPermission' takes 4 arguments

Here is the call of the helper:

```
<%= Html.CheckBoxForWithPermission(m => m.Current, new string[] { Chatham.Web.Business.Definitions.Constants.PERMISSIONS.hasICAdvanced }, Chatham.Web.Business.Definitions.Constants.PERMISSIONS.hasICAdvanced, new { @class = "economicTextBox", propertyName = "Current", onchange = "UseCurrent();UpdateField(this);" })%>
```

And here is the actual method:

```
// CHECKBOX WITH PERMISSIONS
        // WITHOUT -- READONLY
        public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxForWithPermission<TModel>(
                                                          this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
                                                          Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression,
                                                          string[] permissions,
                                                          object htmlAttributes
                                                         )
        {
            foreach (string permission in permissions)
            {
                if (Chatham.Web.UI.Extranet.SessionManager.PhysicalUser.IsInRole(permission))
                {
                    // the user has the permission => render the checkbox
                    return htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
                }
            }
            // the user has no permission => render a readonly checkbox
            var mergedHtmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
            mergedHtmlAttributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
            return htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(expression, mergedHtmlAttributes);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit looks like the problem:

```
new string[] {
    Chatham.Web.Business.Definitions.Constants.PERMISSIONS.hasICAdvanced
}, 
Chatham.Web.Business.Definitions.Constants.PERMISSIONS.hasICAdvanced
```

I think that should be:

```
new string[] {
    Chatham.Web.Business.Definitions.Constants.PERMISSIONS.hasICAdvanced,    
    Chatham.Web.Business.Definitions.Constants.PERMISSIONS.hasICAdvanced
}
```

Your current code is trying to pass in an array with one permission, and then another single string... whereas presumably you *meant* to pass in an array with both permissions.

Having said that, both permissions are the same here... that looks unintentional too. What permissions were you *trying* to use?

(Just out of interest, for the sake of readability - can't you add a using directive to let you just refer to `PERMISSIONS.hasICAdvanced`?)

Comment: I am such a moron. My head is not in the game today. Thank you.